# How to pause and resume asynchronous consumption of JMS messages

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Iam building an application using activeMQ where i have a producer and a consumer.
         In the consumer iam using a MessageListener to asynchronously listen to messages from producer which is done using a method called onMessage(Message message).
         But before consuming the messages i want to perform a condition check and then consume the messages.
         I do not want to use synchronous consumption of message because it will be against my design.

```
  void initialize() throws JMSException {
            this.connection = this.connectionFactory.createConnection();
            this.connection.start();
            final Session session = this.connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            final Destination destination = session.createQueue("testQ");
            this.consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
            this.consumer.setMessageListener(this);
}
```

**Check Condition here like detection of internet connection etc**

```
public void onMessage(final Message message) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(message);

        if (!(message instanceof TextMessage)) {
            _LOG.error("The message is not of type TextMessage but of type {} so we could not process", message.getClass().getSimpleName());
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This type '" + message.getClass().getSimpleName() + "' of message could not been handled");
        }

        try {
            final String messageType = message.getStringProperty("messageType");
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(messageType);
            _LOG.info("The MessageType is {}", messageType);

            final String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(msg);
            _LOG.debug(msg);

            process(messageType, msg);
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            _LOG.error("We could not read the message", e);
        }
    }
```

Any code example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear as to why you want to make checks because if there is any issue with connection, then your application would be notified of such error. You can setup an ExceptionListener for JMS Connection which will get invoked if there is an issue with connection.

The onMessage would not be called if there is a connection issue.

Also I would push the connection.start() method call after setting up the message listener for consumer. A connection.start() invocation indicates to messaging provider that the application is ready to receive messages.

There is connection.stop() to pause/stop message delivery. You can issue  connection.start() again to resume message delivery.

---

**Update based on your response**

I suggest you use a session with client acknowledge mode.

```
final Session session = this.connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
```

Then in `onMessage` method, if there is no internet connection, don't acknowledge the message. The message will be delivered again if it has not expired.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Right I will describe my scenario.Assume the message i consume from activemq queue ,i want to send it to a webservice and before sending to a webservice iam checking if the internet connection is present or not.If the internet connection is not present i want to pause consuming the messages from MessageListener which will eventually expire in the activemq due to expiry time(which is according to my design) and if the internet connection is up i send the messages to webservice.Can you help me by editing my onMessage code which i have posted above.

Comment: public void onMessage(final Message message) {
    if(isNetavailable()==false)
      {
       try {
        this.connection.stop();
       } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      else if(isNetavailable()==true)
      {
       try {
        this.connection.start();
       } catch (JMSException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
    } My question here is after i invoke connection.stop() in Onmessage if there is no internet connection, then will the Onmessage be invoked the next time to perform connection.start()

Comment: ublic void onMessage(final Message message) {
    if(isReachable==false){ return;} else

Comment: If you issue connection.stop, then onMessage will not be invoked till connection.start is called by your application. So you need to call connection.start outside of onMessage. Also it's illegal to call connection.start in onMessage method.

Answer (score 1):

In Asynchronous messaging you can always check the condition before processing the message. Once the JMS message received at your Listener code(i.e. OnMessage method ) it is up to you to give the further direction. I had solved such problem where I wanted to check the JMS message with my db Content.

check the internet connection is alive by making urlConnection to the webservice url something like below:

```
  public static boolean isReachable(String targetUrl) throws IOException
{
   try {
     HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
        targetUrl).openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");


    int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

    return responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
} catch (UnknownHostException noInternetConnection)
  {
    return false;
   }
}
```

And then in your onMessage method call the method as

```
public void onMessage(final Message message) {
    if(isReachable){
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(message);

    if (!(message instanceof TextMessage)) {
        _LOG.error("The message is not of type TextMessage but of type {} so we could not process", message.getClass().getSimpleName());
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This type '" + message.getClass().getSimpleName() + "' of message could not been handled");
    }

    try {
        final String messageType = message.getStringProperty("messageType");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(messageType);
        _LOG.info("The MessageType is {}", messageType);

        final String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(msg);
        _LOG.debug(msg);

        process(messageType, msg);
    } catch (final JMSException e) {
        _LOG.error("We could not read the message", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A query about AUTOACKNOWLEDGE.Iam using AUTOACKNOWLEDGE & as you see in Onmessage there is a method process(messageType, msg).If process() throws exception will the activeMQ perfom a retry to send the same message continuously?In my case assume iam sending message to process() & there is no internet that message is sent to webservice inside process()  7 times with 1 sec difference if i get a ConnectionRefused Exception or 404 error etc i.e. process(messageType, msg) is called 7 times.But if i get a 200OK  process(messageType, msg) is called once.Why is this & what i need to do to avoid it.

Comment: Is the activeMQ waiting for auto acknowledgement from OnMessage which it is not getting due to exceptions in process(messageType, msg) where the process returns a Retrofit.client.Response.Is that the reason it is retrying to send messages 7 times.